# How do i fetch data of games like pubg mobile for a tournament app?

Tags: android

I am making an android app for my final year project. It is an gaming tournament application. I have just started the project, so i want to know if i can get the data of different games to my app through any way? I want this data to determine the winners of the tournaments.

I have seen some basics about content provider for android. But I have read on some websites that the data of these games are protected and can't be fetched.

Comment: The information you are looking for, if publicly available (may cost $), would be available from an "API." Google PUBG API and you may find what you need.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You must use their api to retrieve the data. Here is their [developer portal](https://developer.pubg.com/)

Comment: pubg mobile data is not available in that portal

Comment: is there any way to get mobile pubg data